# sorting a dataframe and keep only the first specific numbers of rows with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

if I have a dataframe created from these lists:

```
users= ['user 1','user 1','user 1','user 1','user 1','user 1',
        'user 2','user 2','user 2','user 2','user 2','user 2',
        'user 3','user 3','user 3','user 3','user 3','user 3']

control_users= ['c_user 01','c_user 02','c_user 03','c_user 04','c_user 05','c_user 06',
                'c_user 01','c_user 02','c_user 03','c_user 04','c_user 05','c_user 06',
                'c_user 01','c_user 02','c_user 03','c_user 04','c_user 05','c_user 06']

distance = [0.51, 0.62, 0.62, 0.05, 0.56, 0.64, 0.55, 0.23, 0.92, 
            0.02, 0.56, 0.65, 0.24, 0.55, 0.66, 0.11, 0.98, 0.99]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(users,control_users,distance)),columns=['users','control_users','distance'])
```

the dataframe:

```
     users control_users  distance
0   user 1     c_user 01      0.51
1   user 1     c_user 02      0.62
2   user 1     c_user 03      0.62
3   user 1     c_user 04      0.05
4   user 1     c_user 05      0.56
5   user 1     c_user 06      0.64
6   user 2     c_user 01      0.55
7   user 2     c_user 02      0.23
8   user 2     c_user 03      0.92
9   user 2     c_user 04      0.02
10  user 2     c_user 05      0.56
11  user 2     c_user 06      0.65
12  user 3     c_user 01      0.24
13  user 3     c_user 02      0.55
14  user 3     c_user 03      0.66
15  user 3     c_user 04      0.11
16  user 3     c_user 05      0.98
17  user 3     c_user 06      0.99
```

If I want to sort the dataframe with 2 conditions: keep only the first 2 rows of each user, and the control users are not repeated.

The purpose is to assign only 2 closest unique control users for each user, if a control user is already matched with a user, it won't be matched again with the others.

And if the distance is equal between many pairs of them, the user that has the lowest index number will have the priority to get the control user first.

the result should look like this:

```
     users control_users  distance
9   user 2     c_user 04      0.02
7   user 2     c_user 02      0.23
12  user 3     c_user 01      0.24
4   user 1     c_user 05      0.56
2   user 1     c_user 03      0.62
14  user 3     c_user 03      0.66
```

I only know how to sort it:

```
df.sort_values(by=['distance'],ascending=True)
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance